Error in the energy norm for inhomogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions
Short description
When conducting FEM analysis with inhomogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions, I compute the error in the energy norm with an expression that should only work for problems with homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions. Still, when performing $h$-refinement, the error estimation indicates theoretical convergence rates. My question is simple: Why?
Below, I provide some basic information for the context, and my problem is then re-stated again at the end of this post in more detail.
Note that I do not have a major in higher mathematics and functional analysis, so forgive me if my formulations are not as thorough and firm as they perhaps should be.

Problem statement
Consider a weak problem statement
\begin{equation}
\text{find}~u \in \mathcal{S},~\text{such that}~~ a(u,v) = f(v)~~\forall v \in \mathcal{V}\,,
\end{equation}
and its discretized version
\begin{equation}
\text{find}~u^\mathrm{h} \in \mathcal{S}^\mathrm{h},~\text{such that}~~ a(u^\mathrm{h},v^\mathrm{h}) = f(v^\mathrm{h})~~\forall v^\mathrm{h} \in \mathcal{V}^\mathrm{h}\,,
\end{equation}
where $a(\cdot,\cdot)$ is a symmetric bilinear operator, while $f(\cdot)$ denotes a linear operator. Furthermore, $\mathcal{S}$ and $\mathcal{V}$ refer to the trial and test function spaces, respectively. Functions in $\mathcal{S}$ fulfill the prescribed (possibly inhomogeneous) Dirichlet boundary conditions, while functions in $\mathcal{V}$ vanish at the Dirichlet boundary. Finally, $\mathcal{S}^\mathrm{h} \subset \mathcal{S}$ and $\mathcal{V}^\mathrm{h} \subset \mathcal{V}$ denote the discretized finite dimensional subspaces.
Error estimation
For the error estimation, I use the energy norm
\begin{equation}
||e||_a = \sqrt{a(e,e)}\,,
\end{equation}
where $ e = u^\mathrm{h} -u$ denotes the absolute error between the approximated and true solutions. The neat thing about the energy norm (and many other norms) is that expected theoretical convergence rates upon $h$-refinement can be formulated a priori. Thus, when these expected convergence rates show up in the simulation, one is reassured about a correct implementation of the FEM code.
Homogeneous boundary conditions
Assuming homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions, $\mathcal{S}^\mathrm{h} = \mathcal{V}^\mathrm{h}$ holds. Following from the way how we defined the error $e$ and from the fact that $a(\cdot,\cdot)$ is symmetric and bilinear, we may write
\begin{equation}
a(u,u) = a(u^\mathrm{h}-e,u^\mathrm{h}-e) = a(u^\mathrm{h},u^\mathrm{h}) -\underbrace{2a(u^\mathrm{h},e)}_{=0} + a(e,e)\,,
\end{equation}
where $a(u^\mathrm{h},e)$ vanishes due (i) to the Gelerkin orthogonality stating $a(v^\mathrm{h},e)=0,~\forall v^\mathrm{h} \in \mathcal{V}^\mathrm{h}$ and (ii) to assuming homogeneous Dirichlet BCs $u^\mathrm{h} \in \mathcal{S}^\mathrm{h}=\mathcal{V}^\mathrm{h}$. Thus, the above expression leads to the simple equation for computing the error
\begin{equation}
a(e,e) = a(u,u) - a(u^\mathrm{h},u^\mathrm{h})\,.
\end{equation}
This is really convenient since the strain energies associated with the reference $a(u,u)$ (typically coming from an analytically computed or overkill FEM reference solution) and numerical solutions $a(u^\mathrm{h},u^\mathrm{h})$ are clearly separated.
Inhomogeneous boundary conditions (problematic case)
In the case of inhomogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions, $\mathcal{S}^\mathrm{h} \neq \mathcal{V}^\mathrm{h}$ holds. Thus, the Galerkin orthogonality for $a(u^\mathrm{h},e)$ does not apply, i.e., the term does not vanish. Consequently, after unpacking $a(u^\mathrm{h},e)$ and rearranging the terms, we arrive at
\begin{equation}
a(e,e) = a(u,u) + a(u^\mathrm{h},u^\mathrm{h}) - 2a(u,u^\mathrm{h})
\end{equation}
for the error. Here, the correct error estimation should also include the computation of the mixed term $a(u,u^\mathrm{h})$.
And here comes my "problem": For the inhomogeneous case, I use the equation for $a(e,e)$ associated with the homogeneous case and still get theoretical convergence rates... According to my current understanding, I am making a mistake by not computing $2a(u,u^\mathrm{h})$, yet, the convergence rates seem not to care.
FYI: For many of my problems, the reference strain energy $a(u,u)$ is computed analytically, i.e., its value is exact.

Many thanks for your help!
Best regards,
Márton

Not sure if I understand your question correctly. You compute the wrong error expression and get the correct convergence rate? If the implementation is correct, then it tells you that the neglected terms are of the same or higher order. Maybe you could compute/estimate them?

Thank you for your quick comment! There must be a reason why neglecting the mentioned term does not influence the convergence rate, and your reasoning seems correct. As I have encountered this phenomenon for all kinds of problems in structural mechanics with inhomogeneous Dirichlet BCs, I thought there must be an explanation for this in some FEM textbooks. Yet, I don't seem to find any. Could you perhaps elaborate on how you would go about computing/estimating the order of the mentioned term? I never had to do something like that.

I think you could just use the usual trick of decomposing $u = u_0 + u_D$ where $u_0 \in \mathcal{V}$ and $u_D$ satisfies the boundary condition. The equation is linear so the $u_D$ term becomes a contribution to the rhs, $f(v) \mapsto f(v) - a(u_D, v)$. This seems like it turns the problem into the previous case with homogeneous b. c. At least this is how I would analyze the system to prove solvability, seems natural to try to use the same trick here, but I am no expert in error analysis.
